# Error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

The following error I am getting while retrieve the local database data:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT EVENT_USER_ID,EVENT_ID,RINGEE_USER_ID,IS_INVITED,IS_ATTENDING,IS_DELETE FROM user_relationWHERE _ID =1`

The query for `user_relation` table is below,

```
public static abstract class UserRelationTable {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_relation";
    public static final String COL1_EVENT_USER_ID = "EVENT_USER_ID";
    public static final String COL2_EVENT_ID = "EVENT_ID";
    public static final String COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID = "RINGEE_USER_ID";
    public static final String COL4_IS_INVITED = "IS_INVITED";
    public static final String COL5_IS_ATTENDING = "IS_ATTENDING";
    public static final String COL6_IS_DELETE = "IS_DELETE";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL1_EVENT_USER_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL2_EVENT_ID + INTEGER_TYPE
            + COMMA_SEP + COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL4_IS_INVITED + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL5_IS_ATTENDING + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL6_IS_DELETE + INTEGER_TYPE + ")";

    public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

    public static final String RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA = "SELECT " + COL1_EVENT_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL2_EVENT_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL4_IS_INVITED + COMMA_SEP + COL5_IS_ATTENDING + COMMA_SEP
            + COL6_IS_DELETE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE _ID =";
}
```

How to solve this error help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add space before `WHERE`:

```
public static final String RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA = "SELECT " + COL1_EVENT_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL2_EVENT_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL4_IS_INVITED + COMMA_SEP + COL5_IS_ATTENDING + COMMA_SEP
            + COL6_IS_DELETE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE _ID =";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static final String RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA = "SELECT " + COL1_EVENT_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL2_EVENT_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL4_IS_INVITED + COMMA_SEP + COL5_IS_ATTENDING + COMMA_SEP
            + COL6_IS_DELETE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE _ID =";
```

**You have not given the space after tablename, that's why this error occurs.**

Comment: Hey, have you checked it?

Comment: Ok, if this answer is helpful to you, please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

in your code String RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA

***"WHERE _ID ="***  tends to ***" WHERE _ID ="***
always mark this For ***DATABASE***

### simple and easy

SPACE **After** SELECT,CREATE,DELETE,UPDATE etc...

and SPACE **both** **side** WHERE,LIKE,IN,FROM,etc.....